# Swift Timer Manager as Singleton or Use Dependency Injection?

Tags: timer

I am creating an iOS application that relies heavily on the `Timer` class. I am to the point in my development at which I need to create the timer management class.

Because the timer needs to be visible in most of my view controllers, I need a way to allow necessary view controllers access to the timer manager. I am trying to decide between three options:

1. Using a singleton because there will only be one instance of the timer running at any given time.
2. Creating the timer in the view controller that is responsible for creating it and posting notifications for the view controllers that need to display the time.
3. Creating the timer in the view controller that is responsible for creating it and using dependency injection to pass it to other view controllers.

From a testability standpoint, is one of the options a better solution over the other? I am diving into TDD and want to ensure that I have a testable solution.

Comment: Any progress on this @NickKohrn ? I'm trying to implement something similar using a timer singleton, but can't get the selector to fire.